# failed to run '/usr/bin/bash': no such file or directory

Tags: windows, git-bash

I've been using gitbash these past few days and it's working just fine. But a while ago, after install a pdf reader with patch file, when I opened my gitbash it gave me the error which says "Failed to run '/usr/bin/bash': No such file or directory".  I don't know what happened and why, but I think the patch file of the application that I installed has something to do with it. My pc antivirus prompted a warning, and I took actions. Then the trouble in the gitbash happened. Please help me, I don't want to reinstall gitbash again coz I also have to install some things.

Comment: I assume you still have /usr and /usr/bin, it's just /usr/bin/bash that has been deleted? Do you still have /bin/bash? They are (AFAICS) the same file in my git bash, so you could copy or link /bin/bash to /usr/bin/bash to get it back?

Comment: And why have you tagged this reactjs? I can't see how it is related to that.

Comment: nope, I don't have the bash anymore when I checked it. How can I have it back?

sorry for tagging react, I don't know what else to tag. sorry.

Comment: Oh I see..so I'll just copy the bash from bin to user/bin?

Comment: If it's there I expect that would work, yes. If that's been deleted too then I expect you'll have to reinstall sorry. But the reinstall should just overwrite the git installation, and shouldn't break any configuration you've set up - unless you've customised the installed version of git it ought not cause you any problems.

Comment: I've copied it, but when I open the gitbash again, it would open then close instantly.

Comment: Oh, you're right - sorry. I did diff the two files from inside git bash and it said they were the same, but I see now the files on disk are very different. I guess you'll need to reinstall then, or try and extract the file from the installer or copy it from an installation on another machine.

Comment: Check your antivirus software, maybe bash is being quarantined, you will have to release it.

Comment: oh, I see. Thank you so much. I'll look into my antivirus. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue, searched for it, this is one of the first few results. So if you are looking why you got this message recently: **check your antivirus** and that the folder and the file actually exist. As previous answers mentioned, reinstall helps bring it back, but antivirus might break it again. So I would check your antivirus GUI and see if you can restore it and add an exception.

Mine was that Avast antivirus classified it as 'IDP.Generic' threat (weirdly only when I would close the shell with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> on Windows 10).

Comment: You are right. I turned off all of the functions of Avast antivirus for 10 minutes and reinstalled MSYS2, then it worked. Also, read [this](https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=219993.0). I had exactly the same symptom as you had. During the installation, my Avast antivirus detected an 'IDP.Generic' threat and I decided to quarantine it. Then, I ran MSYS2 and got `/usr/bin/bash: Exit 126.
Failed to run '/usr/bin/bash': No such file or directory`. There were `basenc.exe` and `bashbug` under `/usr/bin/`, but there was no `bash` between them. Now it works, thanks to you.

Answer (score 3):

to resolve this issue simply reinstall git.

Comment: It worked but on every time system start/restart, I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I disabled Avast antivirus software
Then uninstalled and reinstalled git

It worked for me:)

Answer (score 1):

Like jack this was caused by my virus scanner(avast). To resolve I opened the quarantine page restored and added exemption.

Answer (score 0):

Try 'echo $PATH' in CygWin Terminal to get the PATH it must written something like

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program
>   Files/TortoiseHg:/home

Depending on the **Chroot** in you **sshd_config** it looks for the **/bin/bash** file

you will have three options

1. you might have to copy the files into the Chroot mentioned folder and give the permission.
2. You can update with you Chroot
3. Or bind mounting would also help

[ref](https://serverfault.com/questions/254233/ssh-fails-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue simply **deactivate** your antivirus while reinstalling git.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I did the Same Avast caused it, so I download Git again from [enter link description here](https://gitforwindows.org/)
And stopped Avast from doing it again by adding exceptions

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need to uninstall git bash. The problem for me was that my antivirus quarantined `usr/bin/bash` and classified it as an 'IDP.generic' threat. I clicked on the "restore and add exception" option and now my git bash works just fine.
The problem is most likely your anti-virus (especially if it's avast) causing unintentional harm.